# How to send long strings to a php file without a form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a textarea inside a form (form action=post) and a link under this textarea, the user should fill this textarea and click the button to transfer the text written in the texarea to another file, I'm using jQuery to grab the textarea content and append them to the href of the link, this was working fine until I was testing the textarea with long strings.

so what is the alternative for sending very long strings to another php files ?

and thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use a form?

Comment: the textarea is in a form and this textarea is not intended to be saved, and the form uses POST to another file, and I don't think we can use a form inside another one according to w3c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $.post , there is no size-limit for POST-data.

But when you want the behaviour of a link(opening the target-page), you'll need a form.

A simple approach:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
/**
  * @param o mixed selector/element to send
  * @param a string url to send to
  * @param m optional string HTTP-method (default: 'post')
  * @param t optional string target-window(default: '_self')
  **/
function fx(o,a,m,t)
{
  $('<form/>')
    .attr({action:a,method:m||'post',target:t||'_self'})
      .css('display','none')
        .append($(o).clone())
          .appendTo('body')
            .submit()
              .remove();
}
</script>


<form>
 <input name="foo">
 <textarea id="textareaId" name="bar">foobar</textarea>
 <a style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline" 
    onclick="fx('#textareaId','some.php')">send only the textarea</a>
</form>
```

It creates a new form on the fly, appends the desired element to the form and sends the form(to wherever you want to)

Comment: I didn't know that there's no limit for POST data, thank you I'll try $.post

Comment: Actually, there is a `POST_MAX_SIZE` directive in the PHP configuration. It's much less likely to be reached than the character limit of a URL string though.

Comment: @JimD and what about jQuery's $.post ?

Comment: @Jim D, of course you're right, there may be limit's too on post, but I don't think that they matter in that case.

Comment: Peter You're still posting to a PHP file, so the limit would still apply. However, @Dr.Molle is right in that it's very unlikely for you to reach this limit with the contents of a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with POST method :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  alert("Success");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the number of charachters you can send in a URL. [IE url limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

That might have been your problem.

But you could use post in jquery as well